# Plain socket vs SSL socket

Tags: sockets, ssl

What is the difference between a plain socket vs a ssl socket (with respect to openSSL)?

Can a client connect to port 443 (https) on the server on a plain socket and then initiate a ssl Handshake?

Answer (score 2):

The only distinction between plain communication and SSL communication is the protocol. There's also nothing special about port 443, other than that it *expects* to communicate over the SSL protocol.

As a result, a client can definitely connect to port 443 using nothing special, and as long as they send the correct bytes (those which represent an SSL handshake), any server listening for SSL connections on port 443 will respond.

If by 'plain socket' and 'ssl socket' you mean something API specific, like a Java `EncryptedSSLSocketConnection`, then please clarify.

Comment: Thanks. The distinction I referred to is with respect to OpenSSL api for C++. The function names are 
1. connect(plain socket connect call from winsock.h) 
2.SSL_connect(ssl socket connection for SSL.h)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  OpenSSL's classic (non-BIO) API is designed to support exactly that type of usage, allowing an SSL/TLS session be attached to an existing socket at any time.  HTTPS is not a good example of this usage, since HTTPS requires handshaking immediately upon connecting.  Think more like POP3 or SMTP, which support STARTTLS commands to dynamically initiate an SSL handshake after both parties have explicitally agreed to it over a plain connection first.